# AIR apps for iOS

Tags: ios, air

I'm developing AIR apps in Flash and Flash Builder 4.6. I've put several of these on my server. When I try a download from an iPad / iPhone it errors and says the app can't be installed. Do iOS devices need the AIR sdk installed to view AIR apps? Thanks in advance. Rob - http://www.putnamassociates.com/Apps/newApps.html

Comment: First do you have a paid Apple developers account for iOS. Because to run apps in an iOS device you will need to sign them with an provisioning profile. You can add 100 device to your account on which an ad-hoc version of your app can run. You will also need to add the device, once registered, to the provisioning profile.

Comment: I do have the account for iOS and they are signed with the provisioning profile but I didn't add the device to the provisioning profile. Based on what you're saying, to view any AIR app on any iOS you first need to register and add the device to the provisioning profile? rckoenes I appreciate your help. Thanks,

Comment: Yes that's correct you will need to have an paid account and add the device, then create a provisioning profile for the app based on the app bundle. Then select the device in you want in the profile.

Comment: Thanks and one last question. For any person with an iPad / iPhone that wants to download an AIR app, they would have to do the above?

Comment: Yes, Apple want you to submit apps to the App Store. They don't want you to distribute apps out side of the App Store.

Comment: That's the answer. I really appreciate your time and help. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to submit you apps to the App-Store or you need to purchase an "Enterprise" Account, with which you can install apps without the app store.